# show one div and hide another div onclick of list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle

div1 = Top 10 Listings
div2 = Send Selected

am looking for functionality that will be having n no. of contacts each with a checkbox when checkbox checked div2 has to be displayed otherwise div1 should have to be displayed... Am entirely new to this forum sry if my qtn is confusing below is what I've achieved upto now... http://jsfiddle.net/0p5cf4be/

now checkbox is working as a toggle
but I need that div2 to display if one/multiple checkbox checked it should stay at div2

at default it should have to show div1

if no checkbox is checked then it have to show div1

```
<script>
  x=false;
  function Check(){
    if(x){    
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display='inline';
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
      x=false;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none'; 
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display='inline';   
      x=true;    
    }
  }
</script>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="div1"> <h2>Top 10 Listings</h2> </a>
  <a href="#" id="div2" style="display:none"> <h2>Send Selected</h2> </a>
</div>
<div class="contacts">
  Contact 1<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="Check()">
  <br>
  Contact 2<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="Check()">
  <br>
  Contact 3<input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="Check()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using jquery to manage the state of div2 based on the state of the checkboxes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a href="#" id="div1">
    <h2>Top 10 Listings</h2> </a>
  <a href="#" id="div2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Send Selected</h2> </a>
</div>
<div class="contacts">
  Contact 1<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
  <br>
  Contact 2<input type="checkbox" id="check2">
  <br>
  Contact 3<input type="checkbox" id="check2">
</div>


<script>
  var allCheckboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

  allCheckboxes.click(
    function () {
      var showSendSelected = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0;
      var sendSelectedLink = $("#div2");
      if (showSendSelected) {
        sendSelectedLink.show();
      } else {
        sendSelectedLink.hide();
      }
    }
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged JQUERY try this,

```
 function Check()
 {
    var y=$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length; 
    if(y!=0)
    {
       document.getElementById("div2").style.display='inline';   
       document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none'; 
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("div1").style.display='inline';
       document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';   
    }
}
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/0p5cf4be/11/

Comment: $("input[type='checkbox']:checked") will not return elements. length will not work at that time

Comment: uncheck all checkboxs and try $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length in your console

Comment: @raghavendra It works absolutely fine check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0p5cf4be/8/

Comment: yes it worked i think i messed up ok thanks for quick respones

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used jQuery tag, use a jQuery handler like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $checks = $('.contacts input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var checked = $checks.is(':checked');
    $('#div1').toggle(!checked);
    $('#div2').toggle(checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="div1"> <h2>Top 10 Listings</h2> </a>
  <a href="#" id="div2" style="display:none"> <h2>Send Selected</h2> </a>
</div>

<div class="contacts">
  Contact 1<input type="checkbox"/>
  <br/>
  Contact 2<input type="checkbox"/>
  <br/>
  Contact 3<input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

---

Without jQuery, you can use a counter like

```js
var counter = 0;

function Check(el) {
  if (el.checked) {
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display = counter ? 'none' : 'block';
  document.getElementById("div2").style.display = counter ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" id="div1"> <h2>Top 10 Listings</h2> </a>
  <a href="#" id="div2" style="display:none"> <h2>Send Selected</h2> </a>
</div>

<div class="contacts">
  Contact 1<input type="checkbox" onclick="Check(this)"/>
  <br/>
  Contact 2<input type="checkbox" onclick="Check(this)"/>
  <br/>
  Contact 3<input type="checkbox" onclick="Check(this)"/>
</div>
```